# JS - How can I call an Object Prototype Method using an Array containing a list of select Properties / Methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods, prototype

I'm trying to render a table using data from an array of objects. These have been created with a constructor which has a number of prototype methods. All the methods work correctly outside of the specific problem I'm having.
The table needs to be rendered dynamically, eventually with user input selecting which columns they want rendered and in which order. As such I'm trying to use a separate array to house the selected fields (filled in manually for now).
Below I have an example of the object, the prototype, the array, and the array of objects forEach method containing a simple console.log.

```
const jsonResultTotal = {
    new_stats: [
        {
            revenue: 'US$200.00',
            cost: 'US$4.09',    
        }]
    };
```

```
jsonResultTotal.prototype = {
    ...jsonResultTotal.prototype,
    roas: function() {
        return (Number(this.revenue.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')) / Number(this.cost.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,''))).toFixed(
       2);
    },
```

```
const rowCellContent = [
        'revenue',
        'cost',
        roas(),
        'roas()'
        roas
        'roas'
    ];
```

```
jsonResultTotal.new_stats.forEach(function(e) {

for (i=0; i<=5;i++){
       console.log(e[rowCellContent[i]])
}
}
```

The result of the above code is

```
'US$200.00'
'US$4.09'
undefined
```

Well, actually that specific `rowCellContent` array will result in `roas() is not defined`, but the point is that none of the methods will work.

If I `console.log(e.roas())` then it works, so accessing the method seems to be fine. I've tried arrow functions in the rowCellContent array, as well as full functions with a return of `this.roas()`, I've tried to used bind on the `e[rowCellContent[i]]`

There doesn't seem to be any issues calling the properties through the array, or calling the prototype methods directly, I just can't get the methods via the array to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because `roas()` is a function call itself to the (nonexistent) `roas` function in the global scope. More concretely, you're trying to do this: `e[roas()]`. To evaluate that expression, `roas` is first called then it's return value is used as the key to access from `e`. But the function in the global scope named `roas` doesn't exist. Perhaps you mean `e[rowCellContent[i]]()`? That allows you to do `e['roas']()`, which calls the function *that does exist* on the object `e`.

Comment: There's a lot that needs to be cleared here. For starters... what is `jsonResultTotal`? We have here an object, which I'd imagine is an instance of the prototype you are building. But then in your prototype you are accessing `this.revenue`. So maybe it's the prototype of the objects inside `new_stats`?

Comment: @AndrewLi - thanks this works! I had tried something very similar, but had the `()` inside the square brackets. 
I'll just need to add in a switch statement to cover properties vs methods and insert the `()` where appropriate.
Thank you, spent several hours on this today and could not Google my way to an answer.